# Is XML subject to the Same Domain Policy in JavaScript when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml

Is XML subject to the Same Domain Policy in JavaScript when using XMLHttpRequest?

- How can I make Cross Domain Requests using Ajax?
- Does Enabled CORS requests be applied for XML?

Comment: What makes you think XML could be exempted from the SOP?

Comment: Add a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origion: *` to the requested file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is XML subject to the Same Domain Policy in JavaScript when using XMLHttpRequest?

**Everything** is subject to the same origin policy when using XMLHttpRequest. The returned content-type is not relevant to it.

> How can I make Cross Domain Requests using Ajax?

This is well covered by the answers to [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

> Does Enabled CORS requests be applied for XML?

Yes. The returned content-type is not relevant to it.