# KMZ layer not showing when using on a different site

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, geoxml3

So I have a KMZ layer showing on my website but won't show anywhere else.
This is my Javascript:

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    var e = RegExp(/^.*\//);
    return e.exec(window.location.href);
}

function initialize() {
    function e() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
            var o = new google.maps.LatLng(e.coords.latitude, e.coords.longitude);
            p ? p.setPosition(o) : p = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: o,
                icon: "http://i.imgur.com/1VTzeOS.png",
                map: map
            }), map.setCenter(t);
        }), setTimeout(e, 3e5);
    }
    var o = new google.maps.LatLng(42.449686, -71.230919), t = o, a = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: o,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), a), geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow: !0,
        zoom: !1
    }), geoXml.parseKmlString(kmlData);
    for (var n = {
        path: "M 0,-1 0,1",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        scale: 2.5,
        preserveViewport: !0
    }, i = 0; i < geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines.length; i++) geoXml.docs[0].gpolylines[i].setOptions({
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        zoom: !1,
        icons: [ {
            icon: n,
            offset: "0",
            repeat: "1px"
        } ]
    });
    var r = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: parent + "parking2.kmz",
        strokeWeight: 20,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        preserveViewport: !0
    });
    r.setMap(map);
    var p = (new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "You are here!"
    }), null);
    e();
}

var parent = getBaseUrl();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

The parking2.kmz layer will not display on for example 127.0.0.1/localhost with xampp or at http://example.com/test/map.html. It will however show on http://example.com/map.html. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you really using the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geoxml3 uses the xmlHttpRequest object to retrieve the KML/KMZ.  That is subject to the Same Origin Policy.  You can only access KML/KMZ from the exact same domain.  Relative URLs should work or you can use a proxy to access data on other domains.

[`google.maps.KmlLayer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview) can only display **publicly available** KML/KMZ (KML/KMZ that Google's servers can access), so won't work with localhost (127.0.0.1/localhost).

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#overview):

> **KML and GeoRSS Layers
>   : Overview**
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API supports the KML and GeoRSS data formats for displaying geographic information. These data formats are displayed on a map using a KmlLayer object, whose constructor takes the URL of a **publicly accessible** KML or GeoRSS file.

Related:
- [Is XML subject to the Same Domain Policy in JavaScript when using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679296/is-xml-subject-to-the-same-domain-policy-in-javascript-when-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thanks for this, apparently this case only happened on the website I was testing on.